# Generate password for AD user account that meets complexity policy

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to create `AD` users automatically. The problem is, making sure the generated password meets the password policy of `AD`.  I don't know what the policy will be, is there a way to determine that at runtime?  This is what I'm using but you can see the complexity is static to `length=16` and `4 non-alphanumeric chars` and might not always work.  I am looking for a way to get the password policy from `AD` so the generated passwords are correct.

```
UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext);                        
                    up.SamAccountName = userId;
                    up.SetPassword(System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(16, 4));                        
                    up.Enabled = false;
                    up.ExpirePasswordNow();    
                    up.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using. I'm getting the password properties using `DirectoryEntry/LDAP`, then use those to create the password.

```
DirectoryEntry child = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://machine/DC=domain,DC=com");
int minPwdLength = (int)child.Properties["minPwdLength"].Value;
int pwdProperties = (int)child.Properties["pwdProperties"].Value;
```

Use the properties when creating the password.

```
UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext);                        
                up.SamAccountName = userId;
                up.SetPassword(System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(minPwdLength,
                                   pwdProperties));                        
                up.Enabled = true;
                up.ExpirePasswordNow();    
                up.Save();
```