# How to set password according to default domain password policy for ad user in C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to generate AD Users using C# `DirectoryEntry` way, but their passwords must meet the default domain password policy.

There are some random generators but they don't meet set the passwords according to the ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy which includes following points.

```
enforce password history: 4 passwords remembered
maximum password age: 60 days
minimum password age: 0 days
minimum password length: 14 characters
password must meet complexity requirements: enabled
store passwords useing reversbbile encryption: disabled
```

I have not checked the following link in execution, but need second opinion about that.

[Generate password for AD user account that meets complexity policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487526/generate-password-for-ad-user-account-that-meets-complexity-policy)

I thought following way:

Executing commandlet `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` commandlet in C# using Powershell and getting its result ( e.g. `MaxLenght`, `MinLenght`, `MaxAge`,...) and these values should be set in the user loaded properties. ( i.e. but that way seems not correct as `pwdLength` property , `MaxAge` and other relavent properties are not available for user object at AD. )

So what could be the right way to achieve that?

Comment: You can query *WHAT* the policy is (e.g. using `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy`).  Windows will *ENFORCE* the policy by refusing to set a password that violates the policy.  But I'm not aware of any API that will generate a fully conforming password for you "automagically".  If that's what you're asking...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : link updated

Comment: @paulsm4 : not api, but a way to conform that restriction.